# Setting textbox width to the remaning width

Tags: java, android, textbox

Please have a look at the following code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/firstNumber"
        />

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In here, the size(width) of the text box is very small. I am trying to set it to fit to the remaining width, but as you can see, it fails. I have used `android:weight=1` as well. Please help, how can I set the width of the text box to the remaining width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to change the horizontal LinearLayout like below. Change width to `match_parent`

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
```

and add `android:weight=1` to the textview

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
 >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/firstNumber"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    />

<EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the layout_width of inner LinearLayout as match_parent

`android:layout_width="match_parent"`